# Why is TADOBlobField.Savetofile only writing 8 Bytes

Tags: delphi, adodb

I have a working application that I have revisited recently.

I store a file in a text field in a MSSQL database.  I read it into an ADOTable and as a TBlobfield call Savetofile to write it to a file on disk.  This has always worked.  However now it is simply saving a 8 byte file rather than the correct file.

I have a vague memory of this happening before and was wondering if anyone has come across it and knows the solution? I am using Delphi 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was directly caused by my having not applied the Delphi 7 Update 1.

This is a known bug in the shipped version of Delphi 7.

Answer (score 4):

Has anything changed in the database (server/version upgrade)?  Client machine (XP? Vista?)?  What is being saved when you call the SaveToFile method (maybe the file is only 8 bytes)?  Could the field be empty/null?

I would recommend not using table based components (TTable, TADOTable, etc) against a set based RDBMS (MSSQL, Oracle, etc), use TADODataSet and make sure you have all the D7/ADO patches applied.

Good luck

Comment: Delphi 7 did not have Update 1 applied.  This is a known bug fixed by Update 1.

Answer (score 1):

Several years ago (older versions of ado), ther was a problem, if the blob field(s) wasn't the last field in the query. I don't know it that still is true